# How to do Basic authentication to web services using websphere 7.0

Tags: java, web-services, websphere

I am trying to do basic authentication for my web services using Websphere 7.0.

I have tried by creating user and group in was and declared security role in web.xml

But getting problem to map the user to my web service provider application.

Is this correct way or is there any better approach for basic authentication using was 7.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Constraint-0</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Constraint-0</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>test</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>test</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: This is correct. What is your problem?

Comment: When deploying EAR or WAR on WebSphere, you have to map security role "test" to real user or group from your user/group account repository. Another way to do it is to add security role mapping into EAR bindings descriptor (ibm-application-bnd.xml)

Comment: Also, do you have enabled "Application security" in WAS (Security->Global security)? Without this option WAS authentication is not going to work...

Comment: In WAS 7.0 for mapping users to roles there is no save or ok button.That is giving problem for me.Now it is resolved by running the websphere after setting the run with server side resources option.Thanks a lot for every one.Specially for Magic Wand